# Load test all requests are failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, load-testing, web-testing, webtest

I have created simple web application project, for that I Added Web and load test. When I tested web test project its working fine, but when I tested the load test then all requests are failed.

Can you please help me how to resolve the above issue?

It showing issues on these things (white space added to make it easier to read):

```
1....at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestTransaction.ResponseReceived
           (IAsyncResult result)
2....at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
     at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
           Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
           ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image of the web test results shows that the web application is on `localhost`. The load test image is from Microsoft's cloud load service. The cloud computer will not have access to the `localhost` of the development computer.

There are two possible solutions.

1. Change the load test to run it on the same machine as the web application. This can be done by altering the radio buttons below `Test run location` in the active `.testsettings` file. The default in a new solution is to use the cloud service.
2. Make the web test use the actual name or IP address of the computer hosting the web application.